# Send by e-mail a `parse_str` data array

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I have a big form, I `serialize` all the data and send them to a PHP page to then send them by e-mail.

My Question is:

How can I send the email all the data without calling it one by one?

I call just a few data, like name, email, but all the others data I would like to add automatically inside the email.

This is my code:

```
    var data = $("#FormWorkspace").serialize();

  //chiamata ajax
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "form-engine.php",
          data: data,
          dataType: "html",
        success: function()
            {
          alert("success" + data);
            },
        error: function()
            {
          alert("no success " + data);
            }
        });
```

and the PHP is:

```
    session_start();

  $nome = urldecode($_POST['nome']);
  $email = urldecode($_POST['email']);
  $phone = urldecode($_POST['phone']);
  $company = urldecode($_POST['company']);
  $nation = urldecode($_POST['nation']);
  $messaggio = urldecode($_POST['messaggio']);

  $myPostVar = array();
  parse_str($_POST['data'], $myPostVar);




//Send mail

$to         = $tua_email;
$sbj        = "Richiesta Informazioni - $sito_internet";
$msg        = "
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body{
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', Arial;
    color:#333;
    font-size:15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Richiesta Preventivo</h1>
<br />
<h2>Dati udente</h2>
<p>Nome:    $nome</p>
<p>Email:   $email</p>
<p>Phone:   $phone</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Paese:   $nation</p>

<h3>Messaggio</h3>
<p>$messaggio</p>

<h3>Prodotti selezionati</h3>

$myPostVar // How I can write here??


<p>Fine</p>

</body>
</html>
";

$from        = $email;
$headers     = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers    .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers    .= "From: $from";

mail($to,$sbj,$msg,$headers); //Invio mail principale.
```

Comment: What does `$_POST["data"]` look like?

Comment: Ciao Luca, in theory it should not take all the form data and insert it into an array? In this way I have back just a array in the email

Comment: What is the content of $nome, $email, $phone, $company and $nation? They should be filled with the data from the form, not `$_POST["data"]` ...

Comment: No, I take this data directly form the `serialize`, but I have other data that I will like to insert in the email but I can't call it one by one. How I can do?

Comment: [foreach](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)?

Comment: I try, was the first things that I did, I try to put inside the html part. but in the email arrive `?>` Probably I write wrong the foreach loop. I used `<?php foreach ($myPostVar as $item) { <li>$item</lI>} ?>`

Comment: Can you add an example of how `$_POST["data"]` looks to your question? It seems you got some of the PHP a bit wrong

Comment: This is a bit of the data I send from the form: `QNT-NIA%20-%20front%20desk=0&QNT-KARYA%20-%20desk%20220=0&`

Comment: Ok, now, if you use foreach, you can also access the keys and then write this into a table

Comment: Ok, So I have to use the foreach in a different way, like i have did before. Can you show me how because I not sure to know how do it. I can write all the data in the html body ?

Comment: I will put this in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As formulated in the Comments, what you'd want to do is access the keys and the values separately:

```php
<?php

$POST = ["QNT-NIA_-_front_desk" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_-_desk_220" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_-_desk_150" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_-_desk_148" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_-_desk_140" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_-_desk_120" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_-_table_74" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_Bridge_-_148" => "0", "QNT-KARYA_Bridge_-_120" => "0", "QNT-UP+_-_riser" => "0", "QNT-LIFTY_-_laptop_riser" => "0", "QNT-SCACCOMATTO_-_shelf/locker" => "0", "QNT-CORAL_-_shelf" => "0", "QNT-ECHO_-_space_divider" => "0", "QNT-KANBAN_BOARD" => "0", "QNT-DAK_-_sofa" => "0", "QNT-FLORA_-_planter" => "0", "nome" => "Nome ", "email" => "marco@email.it", "phone" => "11 111111111", "company" => "PLY", "nation" => "Italy", "messaggio" => "", "fred" => "", "informativa" => "informativa" ];
$articles = [];



$nome = urldecode($POST['nome']);
$email = urldecode($POST['email']);
$phone = urldecode($POST['phone']);
$company = urldecode($POST['company']);
$nation = urldecode($POST['nation']);
$messaggio = urldecode($POST['messaggio']);

$msg = "
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body{
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', Arial;
    color:#333;
    font-size:15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Richiesta Preventivo</h1>
<br />
<h2>Dati udente</h2>
<p>Nome:    $nome</p>
<p>Email:   $email</p>
<p>Phone:   $phone</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Paese:   $nation</p>

<h3>Messaggio</h3>
<p>$messaggio</p>

<h3>Prodotti selezionati</h3>";

// here I begin a table for your products
$msg .= " 
<table style='width:100%' border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Nome Prodotto</th>
    <th>value</th> 
  </tr>
";

$unrelated_keys = ["email", "nome", "phone", "company", "nation", "messaggio", "fred", "informativa"]; // these are the keys that are not related to the data you want in the table

//and add the value and name of each prodcut
foreach($POST as $name => $value) {
    if (!array_intersect($unrelated_keys, array($name)))
    {
        $msg .= '<tr>
        <td>'.$name.'</td>
        <td>'.$value.'</td> 
        </tr>';
    } else 
    {
        // do nothing if the field is email/name/company/etc
    }

}

$msg .= "</table>"; // this ends the table

// and this is the rest of your html
$msg .= "<p>Fine</p>

</body>
</html>
";

$from = $email; 
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n"; 
$headers .= "From: $from"; 

$to         = $tua_email;
$sbj        = "Richiesta Informazioni - $sito_internet";

mail($to,$sbj,$msg,$headers);

?>
```

See it in action here: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/7ay5-wctf

Comment: Ok, this is so interesting! but don't take the data if I write: `$_POST_data = urldecode($_POST['data'])` or  `$_POST_data = $_POST['data']` What I can do for take the all the data?

Comment: PHP seems to do the url decoding automagically, to use all the data you post to it simply rename all occurrences of `$_POST_data` to `$_POST["data"]` 

Comment: Look no works :( I try to rename in this way `$_POST_data = $_POST['data'];` or this   `parse_str($_POST["data"], $articles);`

Comment: Both should work. Is your whole Data string of the same format? I don't see why this didn't work, are you getting any errors displayed (if no, did you turn them off)?

Comment: Yes I think you have right, every website where I look tell me that this need have to works! the data does not appear in the e-mail. The other data I use separated works well. I mean ex: `$nome = urldecode($_POST['nome']);` also if I copy a string like in your example works well...

Comment: Is the table beginning and end in the email? Can you var_dump($_POST["data"]) to make sure that it actually gets to the server?

Comment: Yes the email is correct because arrive all data except for the data in `$_POST['data']` if I try to take a data from specific name this work. Could be the problem is in the `dataType: "html"` ?

Comment: The data not pass, I try to call `$nome = $articles['nome'];` but the data not show up.

Comment: Is it correct that `$_POST['data']` includes a selection of articles/products? It does not include the Data sent through the submit otherwise

Comment: `var_dump($_POST["data"])` give me null but the `alert("success" + data);` give me the data. Yes is a selection of products for ask an estimate

Comment: is `var_dump($_POST)` equal to `alert("success" + data)`?

Comment: Can you post the HTML and how you gather the info posted to the PHP?

Comment: no `alert("success" + data)` I use on `success: function` is success to show me the data and I see al the data I send. the data that are serialize and that we can not make it appear. The only way at moment is call one by one like `urldecode($_POST['email'])`. but I can call it one by one could be a lot!

Comment: Then use foreach on the $_POST array. I completely misunderstood your mapping of values here. What you _think_ is `$_POST["data"]` **is** `$_POST`

Comment: `$_POST["data"]` is not the `var data = $("#FormWorkspace").serialize();` that i send in my ajax ? above is the code of the ajax method. your foreach works well if I add the data manually.

Comment: It should be, what is it then? How is `var_dump($_POST)` different from the data var in js?

Comment: sure the data arrive to the php page all data. The things is the `$_POST_data = $_POST["data"];
  $articles = [];
  parse_str($_POST_data, $articles);` 
doesn't work. What I can try ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169341/discussion-between-luca-and-marco-romano).